# Custom Alert Style with Multiple Theme

Tags: java, android, styles, app-themes

I am confused while using custom alert dialogue styles in my application, due to there being multiple themes in my application. I have three themes in my application, called themeGrey, themeTeal and themePink. I have an alert dialogue style like below

```
style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">

        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
```

I have used it in my app like below

```
mProgress = new ProgressDialog((this), R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
```

Now my question is, how can I define a different style for each theme?
I do not want apply with a conditional. Can I do it by declaring a theme as an item?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved removing style from java code like below

```
mProgress = new ProgressDialog((this));
```

and delcared alert style in theme like below

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogThemeTeal</item>
```

Thanks